# Function crash with no exception trace `Error: could not handle the request` with google cloud functions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I See this is the stack driver logs:

```
2018-11-15 08:37:10.917 WET
function-1
x8256v6gdjvi
Function execution started

2018-11-15 08:37:13.081 WET
function-1
x8256v6gdjvi
Function execution took 2164 ms, finished with status: 'crash'
```

The response from the webhook trigger is a 500 with a `Error: could not handle the request`

What might be the cause of this error? How could I diagnose it?

Its works fine locally...

Comment: Without seeing code, it's impossible to say.

Comment: Unfortunately my code has sensitive info in it, I'll try get a minimal working example to replicate this. Thanks